# A fair die is tossed until the sum of points is 2010. What's the expected number of tosses?

Tags: probability

I have run into the following problem. Toss a fair die and write down the sum of points for all tosses. Stop when the sum first becomes greater or equal to 2010. What is the expected number of tosses?

The answer is around 574.761904 and the solution uses a recurrence relation. I noticed that $\frac{2010}{3.5} \approx 574$, where $3.5$ is the expected number of points that one toss gives. The numbers are remarkably similar. My question is: is there a result in the probability theory that explains this?

Comment: The expected value of a toss is $3.5$ so after a large number of tosses the average outcome should be $3.5$  Hence the expected sum for $N$ tosses is $3.5N$

Comment: Thanks for the intuition! Sure, this is why this seems reasonable. However, what bothers me is that the number of tosses is also a random variable depending on the outcomes of tosses. Notice that the correct answer and the intuitive one are not exactly the same.

Comment: Of course it is not exact...the outcome is not exact in an important sense.  You don't know whether you'll hit the threshold exactly, jump over it and clear it by $1$.  Or by $2$, or by $3$, and so on.  So your threshold covers $6$ different events.  Nor are those events equally probable...if the threshold is $2$ it's much more likely that you hit it exactly than that you clear it by $5$.  That's what causes the small variation.